# VBA Code only fully works when using breakpoint

Tags: excel, vba

I am running into an issue with the code below. The "Cash Flow" sheet will not change the height to fit onto one page.  When I use a breakpoint it works but that line seems to be skip when running the macro.I have tried using Application.Wait but that did not work.   Any thoughts on how I can fix it?  Thanks in advance!

Section of the code that is not working:

```
Sheets("Cash Flow").Select
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
```

Full Code:

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

      'Optimize Macro Speed
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

      'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
      Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    'In Case of Cancel
     NextCode:
     myPath = myPath
     `enter code here` If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

      'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
       myExtension = "*.xls*"

      'Target Path with Ending Extention
       myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

      'Loop through each Excel file in folder
       Do While myFile <> ""
       'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
    
    'Sets Page Height ad Width
      
        Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        ReDim Preserve myArray(i - 1)
        myArray(i - 1) = i
    Next i
    Sheets(myArray).Select
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 0
    End With
    Sheets("Cash Flow").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    
       
    End With
    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPathFile As String


    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ActiveSheet

    'get active workbook folder, if saved
     strPath = wbA.Path
     If strPath = "" Then
      strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
      End If
      strPath = strPath & "\"

      strName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
         

     'create default name for savng file
    strFile = strName & ".pdf"
    strPathFile = strPath & strFile

      'export to PDF in current folder
      ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPathFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
    Loop

     'Message Box when tasks are completed
      MsgBox "Task Complete!"

     ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
     Application.EnableEvents = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

     End Sub
```

Comment: Try removing `DoEvents`. I don't think it does what you have in the comment line. If anything it will do the opposite. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function

Comment: Sadly that did not do the trick.  Still thanks for the help.

Comment: I noticed you have `DoEvents` at the beginning and end of the `Do While` loop. Have you removed **both** of them?

Comment: I did take them both out.  Another thing I noticed is that when I put a breakpoint at  "wb.Close SaveChanges:=True" the excel will show the height as one page, but the PDF that was created will have the Cash Flow on two pages.  Not sure if that helps with figuring out the issue.